# Rails Route question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to setup a route so that if the user goes to http://mysite.com/page.html it is routed to the controller page_controller and the action index.  How would I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The usual setup would be to use ressource mapping for this by adding the following line to routes.rb

map.resources :pages

However that will link to http://mysite.com/pages.html and use pages_controller (notice the plural!). But you should be using plurals anyway if you want to stick to the standard Rails way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a named route:

```
map.page '/page.html', :controller => 'page'
```